# neo4j browser import cypher

Tags: import, neo4j, cypher

**Situation**:
I want to offer a neo4j demo for users who have a fresh installed neo4j on their windows machine. The users are not able (lack of knowledge) to use the console (import-tools).

**Wish**:
What I wish is to load my cypher export file into the neo4j browser. What I don't want it to spend hours to program a sql-like CVS export file (because that's what I'm happy not to use since I use a graph database).

**What I tried and learned:**
1) The webadmin tool does not exists anymore.
2) The LOAD command expects CSV only.

**Question**:
Is there a way or work-around that I have missed?

Comment: Of cause I also tried to past the cypher export directly into the neo4j browser command line. Firstly it does not accept the "begin"-cmd secondly it expects one command and no semicolon (;) etc. So straight forward pasting cypher into the browser failed.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [APOC's import/export procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_export_import). This should give you some options.